# How to insert data from an array into HTML using basic JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-table

I've been trying to learn HTML recently but have reached a problem and would really appreciate some help. My code is below but when I run it, it doesn't actually insert the data into the table, instead it inserts the code.

I've tried changing the order of the code and adding ; in different places but don't know enough HTML to solve the problem.

```
let sortDirection = false;
let personData = [
    {name: 'Dylan', age: 31 },
    {name: 'Hannah', age: 17 },
    {name: 'Dollan', age: 39 },
    {name: 'Elle', age: 3 },
];

window.onload = () => {
    loadTableData(personData);
};

loadTableData(personData);

function loadTableData(personData) {
    const tableBody = document.getElementById('tableData');
    let dataHtml = '';

    for(let person of personData){
        dataHtml+= '<tr><td>${person.name}</td><td>${person.age}</td></tr>';
    };
console.log(dataHtml);
tableBody.innerHTML = dataHtml;

} /* The table data is an id I used in the table */
```

It just doesn't insert the data. Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: add also the relevant HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine, just instead of creating a string `'<tr><td>${person.name}</td><td>${person.age}</td></tr>'` you must use [Template literals (Template strings)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
`<tr><td>${person.name}</td><td>${person.age}</td></tr>`
```

Code:

Using [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const personData = [{name: 'Dylan',age: 31},{name: 'Hannah',age: 17},{name: 'Dollan',age: 39},{name: 'Elle',age: 3}]
const tableBody = document.getElementById('tableData')

tableBody.innerHTML = personData.reduce((a, {name, age}) => 
  a += `<tr><td>${name}</td><td>${age}</td></tr>`, '')
```

```html
<table id="tableData"></table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't tell you how much I appreciate it.

Comment: Yes your code works just fine only the backquotes were missing

Comment: @Apoorv what you mean by "backquotes were missing"? Really do not understand.. Even the code example it is working. Thanks

Comment: @Pintsize21 I have added another solution code example to your answer, but with a code refactor using `Array.prototype.reduce()`.. Hope it helps, thanks

Comment: @YosvelQuintero I was referring to the line `dataHtml+= '<tr><td>${person.name}</td><td>${person.age}</td></tr>';`, in this case it would create rows and cells but their values would be `${person.name} and ${person.age} as Strings` and not the values in the variables. But with ````dataHtml+=`<tr><td>${person.name}</td><td>${person.age}</td></tr>````values of the variables would be inserted in the cells

Comment: @Apoorv now i understand your comments, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can concatenate html and parameter with

```
dataHtml+= '<tr><td>'+person.name+'</td><td>'+person.age+'</td></tr>';
```

as you can see below

```
     let sortDirection = false;
     let personData = [
         {name: 'Dylan', age: 31 },
         {name: 'Hannah', age: 17 },
         {name: 'Dollan', age: 39 },
         {name: 'Elle', age: 3 },
     ];

     window.onload = () => {
         loadTableData(personData);
     };

     loadTableData(personData);

     function loadTableData(personData) {
        const tableBody = document.getElementById('tableData');
        let dataHtml = '';

        for(let person of personData){
            dataHtml+= '<tr><td>'+person.name+'</td><td>'+person.age+'</td></tr>';
        };
        console.log(dataHtml);
        tableBody.innerHTML = dataHtml;

     } /* The table data is an id I used in the table */
```

and your html :

```
    <table id="tableData">

    </table>
```